# How to sense when configured wifi security changes in android

Tags: android, wifimanager, wpa-supplicant

I need to handle a case when desired SSID is connected or configured in list, but meanwhile if its security changes, how should I get notified

currently, I am getting the Supplicant State as "Disconnected" when the desired network is connected and meanwhile if its security changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using this method you can sense when any changes....

```
/** 
 * Uppsala University 
 *  
 * Project CS course, Fall 2012 
 * 
 * Projekt DV/Project CS, is a course in which the students develop software for 
 * distributed systems. The aim of the course is to give insights into how a big 
 * project is run (from planning to realization), how to construct a complex  
 * distributed system and to give hands-on experience on modern construction  
 * principles and programming methods. 
 * 
 * All rights reserved. 
 * 
 * Copyright (C) 2012 LISA team 
 */ 
package project.cs.lisa.networksettings; 

import java.util.List; 

import android.content.Context; 
import android.net.wifi.ScanResult; 
import android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration; 
import android.net.wifi.WifiInfo; 
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager; 
import android.util.Log; 

public class WifiHandler { 
    //constants 
    public static final int WEP = 1;
    public static final int WAP = 2;
    public static final int OPEN_NETWORK = 3;

    public static final String TAG = "LISA_Network";

    /** dfsdfsdfsdf. */ 
    WifiConfiguration wifiConf;             /* WifiConfiguration object */

    /** dfsdfsdfsdf. */ 
    WifiManager wifiMgr;                            /* WifiManager object */

    /** dfsdfsdfsdf. */ 
    WifiInfo wifiInfo;                              /* WifiInfo object */

    /** dfsdfsdfsdf. */ 
    List<ScanResult> wifiScan;              /* List of ScanResult objects */

    /** 
     * Constructor initializes WifiManager and WifiInfo. 
     * @param context 
     */ 
    public WifiHandler(Context context) {
        wifiMgr  = getWifiManager(context);     // gets wifiMgr in the current context 
        wifiInfo = getWifiInfo(context);            // gets wifiInfo in the current context
        wifiConf = getWifiConf(context);            // gets wifiConf in the current context
        wifiScan = getWifiInRange();                    // gets wifiScan in the current context
    } 

    /** 
     * Function checkWifiEnabled checks if the WiFi connection 
     * is enabled on the device.  
     * @param wifiMgr 
     * @return true  if the WiFi connection is enabled, 
     *               false if the WiFi connection is disabled 
     */ 
    public boolean checkWifiEnabled() { 
        // checks if WiFi is enabled 
        return (wifiMgr != null && wifiMgr.isWifiEnabled());
    } 

    /** 
     * Function enableWifi enables WiFi connection on the device. 
     * @param wifiMgr 
     * @return true  if the attempt to enable WiFi succeeded, 
     *               false if the attempt to enable WiFi failed.  
     */ 
    public boolean enableWifi() { 
        // enables WiFi connection 
        return wifiMgr.setWifiEnabled(true);
    } 

    /** 
     * Function disableWifi disables WiFi connection on the device. 
     * @param wifiMgr 
     * @return true  if WiFi connection was disabled, 
     *               false if attempt to disable WiFi failed. 
     */ 
    public boolean disableWifi() { 
        // disables WiFi connection 
        return wifiMgr.setWifiEnabled(false);
    } 

    /** 
     * Function getWifiManager gets the WiFiManager object from the device. 
     * @param context 
     * @return WifiManager object. Also sets the class variable 
     *               wifiMgr as the WifiManager object returned. 
     */ 
    public WifiManager getWifiManager(Context context) {
        WifiManager wifiMgr = null;

        // gets WifiManager obj from the system 
        wifiMgr = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

        if (wifiMgr == null) {
            Log.d("TAG", "WIFI_SERVICE is the wrong service name.");
        } 

        return wifiMgr;
    } 

    /** 
     * Function getWifiInfo gets the current WiFi connection information in a 
     * WifiInfo object from the device. 
     * @param context 
     * @return wifiInfo created object or 
     *               null       if wifi is not enabled. 
     */ 
    public WifiInfo getWifiInfo(Context context) {
        WifiInfo wifiInfo = null;

        // gets WiFi network info of the current connection 
        if (checkWifiEnabled()) { 
            wifiInfo = (WifiInfo) wifiMgr.getConnectionInfo();   
        } 

        if (wifiInfo == null) {
            Log.d("TAG", "WifiInfo object is empty.");
        } 

        return wifiInfo;
    } 

    /** 
     * Function that returns a WifiConfiguration object from the WifiInfo 
     * object from the class. If wifiInfo exists, then we are able to retrieve 
     * information from the current connection  
     * @param context 
     * @return WifiConfiguration object created. 
     */ 
    public WifiConfiguration getWifiConf(Context context) {
        WifiConfiguration wifiConfiguration = new WifiConfiguration();

        if (wifiInfo == null) {
            Log.d("TAG", "WifiInfo object is empty");
            return null; 
        } 

        wifiConfiguration.SSID = wifiInfo.getSSID();
        wifiConfiguration.networkId = wifiInfo.getNetworkId();

        return wifiConfiguration;
    } 

    /** 
     * Creates a new WifiConfiguration object for wifiConf. 
     */ 
    public void clearWifiConfig() { 
        wifiConf = new WifiConfiguration();
    } 

    /** 
     * Function getWifiInRange returns all the WiFi networks that are 
     * accessible through the access point (device AP) found during the 
     * last scan. 
     * @param wifi 
     * @return List of ScanResult containing information on all WiFi networks 
     *               discovered in the range. 
     */ 
    public List<ScanResult> getWifiInRange() {
        // gets ~last~ list of WiFi networks accessible through the access point. 
        return (wifiScan = (List<ScanResult>) wifiMgr.getScanResults());
    } 

    /** 
     * Function that scans for wifi networks available in the devices range. 
     * @return true  if scan started 
     *               false if scan could not be started  
     */ 
    public boolean scanWifiInRange() { 
        if (!checkWifiEnabled()) { 
            return false; 
        } 

        if (!wifiMgr.startScan()) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Failed to scan wifi's in range.");
            return false; 
        } 

        return true; 
    } 

    /** 
     * Function to disconnect from the currently connected WiFi AP. 
     * @return true  if disconnection succeeded 
     *               false if disconnection failed 
     */ 
    public boolean disconnectFromWifi() { 
        return (wifiMgr.disconnect());
    } 

    /** 
     * Function to connect to a selected network 
     * @param networkSSID         network SSID name 
     * @param   networkPassword     network password 
     * @param networkId           network ID from WifiManager 
     * @param SecurityProtocol    network security protocol 
     * @return true  if connection to selected network succeeded 
     *               false if connection to selected network failed 
     */ 
    public boolean connectToSelectedNetwork(String networkSSID, String networkPassword) {
        int networkId;
        int SecurityProtocol = WEP;

        // Clear wifi configuration variable 
        clearWifiConfig(); 

        // Sets network SSID name on wifiConf  
        wifiConf.SSID = "\"" + networkSSID + "\"";
        Log.d(TAG, "SSID Received: " + wifiConf.SSID);
        switch(SecurityProtocol) {
            // WEP "security". 
            case WEP:
                wifiConf.wepKeys[0] = "\"" + networkPassword + "\""; 
                wifiConf.wepTxKeyIndex = 0;
                wifiConf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
                wifiConf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40);
                break; 

                // WAP security. We have to set preSharedKey. 
            case WAP:
                wifiConf.preSharedKey = "\""+ networkPassword +"\"";
                break; 

                // Network without security. 
            case OPEN_NETWORK:
                wifiConf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
                break; 
        } 

        // Add WiFi configuration to list of recognizable networks 
        if ((networkId = wifiMgr.addNetwork(wifiConf)) == -1) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Failed to add network configuration!");
            return false; 
        } 

        // Disconnect from current WiFi connection 
        if (!disconnectFromWifi()) { 
            Log.d("TAG", "Failed to disconnect from network!");
            return false; 
        } 

        // Enable network to be connected 
        if (!wifiMgr.enableNetwork(networkId, true)) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Failed to enable network!");
            return false; 
        } 

        // Connect to network 
        if (!wifiMgr.reconnect()) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Failed to connect!");
            return false; 
        } 

        return true; 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really understood your needs. How is it different to check your networkstate ? Official docs for [SupplicantState](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/SupplicantState.html) states:

> These enumeration values are used to indicate the current
>   wpa_supplicant state. This is more fine-grained than most users will
>   be interested in. In general, it is better to use [NetworkInfo.State](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.State.html).

So how it is different that only check network state change in your app ?

Comment: Let me brief you a scenario here, 
lets say I had a hotspot which is with open security, I connected to it successfully, and render the same in my lists of Wifi's, but after some time if I change the security of Hotspot to WPA2 PSK, here the network is configured for me, and I simply try to reconnect it. but I am not able to sense that its security configurations got changed and I should ask for password here.